# EPPlus - join string with named cell

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I need to create an Excel file in which the user can later adjust a specific information. I'm using C# and EPPlus v6.0.4. For example, if the input is a list of products, I want it to be joined with ' taxes included' string (which can be later changed by the user at Excel):

```
descriptionA -> descriptionA taxes included
descriptionB -> descriptionB taxes included
descriptionC -> descriptionC taxes included
```

I'm assuming two worksheets: `ws1` (parameter) and `ws2` (output list). As shown below, cell `B1` is where the user will be able to change the "taxes included" string.

```
ws1.Cells["A1"].Value = "Additional information:";
excel.Workbook.Names.Add("auxData", ws1.Cells["B1"]);
ws1.Cells["B1"].Value = " taxes included 12%";
```

At the second worksheet (`ws2`) I will have the data being populated.

```
int excelLine = 1;
foreach (var product in productList)
{
    string productDescription = product.Description;
    ws2.Cells["A" + excelLine].Formula = .....;  //need ideas on how to solve this
    excelLine ++;
}
```

At the above `.Formula` I was trying `CONCAT` or similar function but its not working (excel file is generated with errors or the formula is not accepted).

The expected output is a cell value `="product full description variable string" & auxData`, therefore suitable to `B1` text changes by the user (`auxData` is an Excel name to `=ws1!$B$1`).

Answer (score 0):

My own solution was:

```
int excelLine = 1;
foreach (var product in productList)
{
    string cellDescription = "=\"" + product.Description + " -- additional information \" & auxData & \"%\"";
    ws2.Cells["A" + excelLine].Formula = cellDescription;
    excelLine ++;
}
```